# What aerodynamic data (drag/lift curves) exists for the L-159 Alca?

Tags: aerodynamics, datasets, aero-vodochody

*This is one of 3 question in "series" - one question split up in 3 to better reward those responding about each aircraft. Other questions: [A-10](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/aerodynamic-data-drag-lift-curves-for-a-10) [Yak-131](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/aerodynamic-data-for-yak-131)*

L-159 Alca is one 3 planes that are used in the [ArmA 3 combat sumilator](http://arma3.com), but its aerodynamics modelling currently lacks significantly. I'm planning on writing a short "essay" to developers regarding what and how can be specifically fixed in the flight model, but I'd like to back my research with some hard data. Specifically, I'm interested in any of the following:

1. L/AoA
2. D/AoA
3. Side lift/SA (Slide angle)
4. Max G/velocity
5. Flight envelopes (like one below for F-15):

[image: http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/7035/f15str.png]

Torques can well be left out - it's not a full fledged simulator, but the above data can give quite a good estimation of high level characteristics already

Are there any good sources on any of the above data? Low-mach data is good enough for me.

I understand this is a tall order, but, well, SE is for expert answers - maybe a wonder happens and someone here has it? :)

Answer (score 4):

From Wikipedia, the aerofoil for the wings is NACA 64A-012. If you would like a full airplane, you would need to plot it in [DATCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force_Stability_and_Control_Digital_DATCOM). DATCOM is a program that is designed to calculate drag, lift, moment coefficient, etc. on an airplane based on coordinates.

So, [here is a link](http://airfoiltools.com/polar/details?polar=xf-n64012a-il-200000) to the polar data I got.

If you want more accurate alpha increase, you need to download [X-FOIL](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/) and learn to use it (quite a tricky program for certain people).

I am afraid the other data is almost impossible to obtain.

Comment: What is datcom?