# What aerodynamic data exists for the Yak-130?

Tags: aerodynamics, datasets, yakovlev

*This is one of 3 question in "series" - one question split up in 3 to better reward those responding about each aircraft. Other questions: [A-10](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/aerodynamic-data-drag-lift-curves-for-a-10) [L-159](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5092/aerodynamic-data-drag-lift-curves-for-l-159-alca)*

Yak-130 is one 3 planes that are used in the [ArmA 3 combat simulator](http://arma3.com), but its aerodynamics modelling currently lacks significantly. I'm planning on writing a short "essay" to developers regarding what and how can be specifically fixed in the flight model, but I'd like to back my research with some hard data. Specifically, I'm interested in any of the following:

1. L/AoA
2. D/AoA
3. Side lift/SA (Slide angle)
4. Max G/velocity
5. Flight envelopes

Torques can well be left out - it's not a full fledged simulator, but the above data can give quite a good estimation of high level characteristics already

Are there any good sources on any of the above data? Low-mach data is good enough for me.

I understand this is a tall order, but, well, SE is for expert answers - maybe a wonder happens and someone here has it? :)

Comment: Yak-131 is not a real plane and does not exist.

Comment: Well, it's a cancelled project which shares airframe with Yak-130, I know. But for this reason, I'd accept data for Yak-130 just as easily.

Comment: In such a case it would make sense to request information regarding Yak-130. The never completed Yak-131 was to be essentially the same airplane (when considering your 5 criteria) with better targeting systems and designated as an attack aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

> The Yak-130 has a maximum g-loading of +8g to -3g and is capable of executing the flight manoeuvres specific to current operational and developmental combat aircraft, including Su-30, MiG-29, Mirage, F-15, F-16, Eurofighter, F-22 and F-35. This aircraft is of classical swept-wing and empennage monoplane design and light alloy construction with carbon-fibre control surfaces. Kevlar armour protection is fitted to the engines, cockpit and avionics compartment.
>
> Flight angles of attack < 40°.
>
> Speeds:
> – level flight, maximum   1 050 km/h
> – takeoff (full fuel load)    200 km/h
> – landing 195 km/h

Side lift and flight envelope is kind of hard to come by, but I got this information from https://thaimilitaryandasianregion.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/yakovlev-yak-130/.

I would also recommend http://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/yak_130/ as another source to look through. Hopefully I was of any help to you in writing your essay.